# Powershell Get-Process string as name

Tags: powershell

When using Get-Process how can I use a string as -Name?

```
$program = "MyProgram"
Get-Process $program
```

Instead of

```
Get-Process -MyProgram
```

Comment: Why not use `Get-Process -Name MyProgram`?

Comment: For example what Im trying to do is create an array for string with different program names in it and do a foreach to loop that foreach it will get process then do something with it

Comment: The `-Name` parameter accepts and string array: `Get-Process -Name powershell,chrome`. You can then pipe the output to `ForEach-Object` to loop through.

Comment: @AndyArismendi: Why don't you add it as an answer instead of a comment so yoyo can accept this correct answer?

Comment: @Lars you ever answer what you think is the answer only to find out the OP is like oh wait no let me clarify... well that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Powershell will accept the name, no matter what.

```
Get-Process Firefox
```

Will return all running Firefox. Likewise, arrays will work too:

```
Get-Process Firefox, iexplore
```

Or

```
$Proc = @("Firefox","iexplore")
Get-Process $Proc
```

Declares an array explicitly, then checks for each running process.

Of course, as previously stated, you can and *should* use -Name for clarity. But nothing really changes. The script should still read something like:

```
$Proc = @("Firefox","iexplore")
Get-Process -Name $Proc
```

There is also the Where-Object approach:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Firefox"}
```

To do "stuff" with it, just pipe the objects into a script block.

Where-Object:

```
PS C:\> Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Firefox"} | fl $_.ID
```

Returns:

```
Id      : 7516
Handles : 628
CPU     : 1154.1421983
Name    : firefox
```

get-process $Proc | FT ID, Name

Would return:

```
    Id Name
    -- ----
    7516 firefox
    12244 iexplore
    12640 iexplore
```

Or, you could finally use the ForEach-Object as mentioned, and loop through them:

```
Get-Process $Proc | ForEach-Object {If($_.Path -contains "C:\Program Files*"){Write-host "Bad Directory"} else{ write-host "Safe"}}
```

If the running .exe above is running from C:\Program Files* then its writes out "Safe", otherwise it writes "Bad Directory".

Answer (score 0):

Seems by popular agreement, the answer to your question is to provide a string array for the `-Name` parameter of `Get-Process` like so:

```
Get-Process -Name MyProgramA,MyProgramB
```

You can then loop through using the pipeline:

```
Get-Process -Name MyProgramA,MyProgramB | ForEach-Object {$_}
```

You can also use a variable:

```
Get-Process -Name $MyProgramStringArrray
```